# how to count the occurrences of words that are in both arrays? (with php)

Tags: php, arrays, count

if I have an array of two arrays

D[0] = array ("I", "want", "to", "make", "cake", "and", "make", "juice")
D[1] = array ("Sister", "want", "to", "takes", "the", "cake", "that", "i", "made")
how to count the occurrences of words that are in both arrays?

eg output:
word    | array[0]   | array[1]
I        : 1   |      1
want     :  1   |      1
to        : 1    |     1 
make   :    2     |    0 
cake    :   1      |   1 
and     :   1       | 0 
juice   :   1      |   0 
sister  :   0       |  1 
takes    :  0        | 1  
the       : 0         |1 
that      : 0       |  1 
made      : 0        | 1

Answer (score 1):

This solution builds an array with allwords, which is later used for iteration
of the two lookup arrays $d[0] and $d[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uOfI.jpg).
array_unique(array_merge()) to delete duplicate "make" for instance.

The array_count_values() is used for the counting of values.

Finally, for displaying the table, the allwords array is as iterator.

For each word a new row with `id`, `word`, `calc from array1`, `calc from array2`.

Long story, short. Here's the

**PHP**

```
<?php

$d = array();
$d[0] = array("I", "want", "to", "make", "cake", "and", "make", "juice");
$d[1] = array("Sister", "want", "to", "takes", "the", "cake", "that", "i", "made");

$allwords = array_unique(array_merge($d[0], $d[1]));

echo '<table>';
echo '<thead><th>Word ID</th><th>Word</th><th>Array 1</th><th>Array 2</th></thead>';

$array1 = array_count_values($d[0]);
$array2 = array_count_values($d[1]);

foreach($allwords as $id => $word) {
    echo '<tr><td>'. $id . '</td><td>' . $word . '</td>';

    if(isset($array1[$word])) {
        echo '<td>' . $array1[$word] . '</td>';
    } else {
        echo '<td>0</td>';
    }

    if(isset($array2[$word])) {
        echo '<td>' . $array2[$word] . '</td>';
    } else {
        echo '<td>0</td>';
    }
}

echo '</table>';
```

**Result**

[image]